# Windows 7 Search automatically searching federated search

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

I have a a federated search that searches SharePoint. When I press the windows and begin typing I want it to search my machine and the federated search. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be possible. You can add links to do the federated search on your query [as described here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/14687-start-menu-add-search-connectors-start-menu-search.html), but it still has to be launched separately.